# Call java void function without printing any text in the page source

Tags: thymeleaf

Here is my sample thymeleaf code:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    /*[[${model.setPRINTOUTFLG("0")}]]*/

    var flgPrintOut2 = /*[[${model.getPRINTOUTFLG()}]]*/ null;
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

In the source, the result is like this:

[image]

I just want to call the void function without printing any text. How can I do that using Thymeleaf?

I also tried this:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
    /*[[${model.setPRINTOUTFLG("0") == null ? "" : ""}]]*/

    var flgPrintOut2 = /*[[${model.getPRINTOUTFLG()}]]*/ null;
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

But the result becomes like this:

[image]

Comment: Why not call the setter on `model` in your controller method?

Comment: Yeah but there are cases that I have to use it on the front-end Thymeleaf like setting back the value to its default then saving it to the session so it won't print a new excel if the user reloaded the page.

Comment: Is printing the Excel done on GET or POST? If on GET, maybe you can do a POST and a redirect to GET to avoid it?